# Scan .txt files from all folder

Tags: bash, matlab, shell

I have a few folders, named: a0, a1, a2, etc.
In each folder I have a few text files (names do not vary between folders) from which I want to import data into a variable in Matlab.

An example of a text file would be:

txtfile #1: a 1 2 3 4.

txtfile #2: b 5 6 7 8.

So I want to be able to extract the data delimited by 'space', and concatenate it into a variable.
for example:
data3 = 2,6

I am fairly clueless about this. 
I tried converting to xls files but I just have way too many txt files to convert. 
I also tried writing a Shell script that writes those variables into a new txt file but didn't do it well enough, I guess.

Any ideas or directions would be awesome.

Comment: There are multiple questions here (obtaining file list, parsing files, outputting files) and it's not clear which ones you're having issues with. Please ask about one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%Grab list of files using file list
%http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22829-file-list

%Open the file into memory
fid = fopen(filename);
text = fread(fid,'*char')';
text = strtrim(text);

%Make exact element a seperate variable
x = regexp(text,' ','split');
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim fName As String = ("Text1.txt")
        Dim sReader As New StreamReader(fName)

```
    Dim yourVar As String = ""
    Dim line As String = ""
    Do While Not sReader.EndOfStream
        line = sReader.ReadLine
        Select Case line.Split("=")(0) 'Split line at "=" sign
            Case "Data3"
                yourVar = line.Split("=")(1)
        End Select
    Loop
```

Comment: It splt the code up wrong but that will read in a text file line by line which you could use a select to search for something in the text and then set your variables based off of that.